# Binary search gets stuck in infinite loop

Tags: c#

Hello and thanks for your time.

I am trying to improve my problem solving skills and I am doing the following excercise:
https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/shadows-of-the-knight-episode-1

In each turn you are given a direction, for example: "U" for "Up", "DR", for Down Right, etcetera.

**You need to move the character to the goal before N turns.**

We are given W, the array's width, and H, the array's height.

I thought about calculating always the medium point in the direction where the character needs to move.

My current code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

/**
 * Auto-generated code below aims at helping you parse
 * the standard input according to the problem statement.
 **/
class Player
{
    static string lastMoveDirection = "";
    static int increasedMoveUnit = 0;
    static int W;
    static int H;
    static int X0;
    static int Y0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] inputs;
        inputs = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        W = int.Parse(inputs[0]); // width of the building.
        H = int.Parse(inputs[1]); // height of the building.
        int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // maximum number of turns before game over.
        inputs = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
         X0 = int.Parse(inputs[0]);
         Y0 = int.Parse(inputs[1]);


        // game loop
        while (true)
        {
            N--;
            string bombDir = Console.ReadLine(); // the direction of the bombs from batman's current location (U, UR, R, DR, D, DL, L or UL)

            // Write an action using Console.WriteLine()
            // To debug: Console.Error.WriteLine("Debug messages...");

            Console.Error.WriteLine("Batman pos: " + X0 + " " + Y0); 
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Bomb direction: " + bombDir);
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Width of the array: " + W);
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Height of the array: " + H);

            if(lastMoveDirection == bombDir)
                increasedMoveUnit++;
            else
                increasedMoveUnit = 0;

            switch(bombDir)
            {
            case "DR":
                X0=CalcMoveDistance("X");
                Y0=CalcMoveDistance("Y");
                break;
            case "DL":
                X0=CalcMoveDistance("X", -1);
                Y0=CalcMoveDistance("Y");
                break;
            case "D":
                 Y0=CalcMoveDistance("Y");
                 break;
            case "UR":
                X0=CalcMoveDistance("X");
                Y0=CalcMoveDistance("Y", -1);
                break;
            case "UL":
                X0=CalcMoveDistance("X", -1);
                Y0=CalcMoveDistance("Y", -1);
                break;
              case "U":
                Y0=CalcMoveDistance("Y", -1);      
                break;
            case "L":
                X0=CalcMoveDistance("X", -1); 
                break;
            case "R":
                X0=CalcMoveDistance("X");  
                break;
            }


            // the location of the next window Batman should jump to.
            Console.WriteLine(X0.ToString() + " " + Y0.ToString());
            lastMoveDirection = bombDir;
        }
    }

    private static int CalcMoveDistance(string axis, int direction = 1) 
    {
        int result = 0;
        switch(axis)
        {
        case "X":
            result = (W+X0*direction)/2;
            break;
        case "Y":
            result = (H+Y0*direction)/2;
            break;
        }


        if(axis == "Y" && result + increasedMoveUnit >= H)
            result = H-1;

        else if(axis == "X" && result + increasedMoveUnit >= W)
            result = W-1;
        else
            result += increasedMoveUnit * direction;

        return result;
    }
}
```

I am facing the following difficulty:

Character starts on (6,6)
It moves Down Right to (23,33)

Correct.

Character starts on (23,33)
It moves Down Right to (32,47)

Correct.

Character starts in (32,47)
It moves Up Right to (36,6)

Correct.

Character starts in (36,6)
It moves Down Right to (38,33)

Correct.

Character starts in (38,33)
It moves Down to (38,46)

Correct (Very close to the target).

**Character starts in (38,46)
It moves Up to (38,7)
Very far from Objective...**

Character starts in (38,7)
It moves Down to (38, 33)

Closer to the objective than before...

Character starts in (38,7)
It moves Down to (38,47)

It is very close to the objective...

**Character starts in (38,47)
Moves Up to (38, 6)
Very very far from Objective in the Y axis...**

**And we keep moving in loop:
Down to (38,33) 
Down to (38, 47)
Up to (38,6)**

Comment: You should update an upper and lower bound values for each axis so the area you are searching gets smaller with each movement. On your first Up Right movement you jump to a Y position from 47 of 6 when you already know it is below 33. Your code has forgotten this piece of information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's because you have:

```
while (true)
```

and nowhere in the `for` loop that breaks it.

Seems like you want:

```
while (N >= 0)  // Or just N > 0, depending on your desired use
```

since you decrement `N` at the beginning of the loop

Comment: Hello Greg, thanks for your help. The program ends itself when N is zero, because of it stops sending you Input Movements.

Comment: I'm not sure that is correct.  I set `N = 1` and it continues after two movements.